# Blurry CSS tooltips on Chrome on Windows

Tags: css, google-chrome, tooltip

I personally can't recreate the problem, but a user is seeing blurring on the text within tooltips. She's running an up-to-date version of Chrome on a modern Windows machine. She says it's pretty hard to even make out what the text says.

```css
/* The question mark that the user clicks on */
.tooltip_wrapper {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: #ececec;
  color: #555;
  cursor: help;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", Impact, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); /* WebKit flicker fix */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* WebKit text rendering fix */
    z-index: 900;
}

.tooltip_wrapper .tooltip {
  background: #1496bb;
  bottom: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  left: -25px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  opacity: 0; /* This hides the box when not hovering */
  padding: 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(10px);
     -moz-transform: translate(10px);
      -ms-transform: translate(10px);
       -o-transform: translate(10px);
          transform: translate(10px);
/* These used to be all translateY */
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all .25s ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all .25s ease-out;
       -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
          transition: all .25s ease-out;
  /* -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
     -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
      -ms-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
       -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
          box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28); */
}

/* This bridges the gap so you can mouse into the tooltip without it disappearing */
.tooltip_wrapper .tooltip:before {
  bottom: -20px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

/* CSS Triangles - see Trevor's post */
.tooltip_wrapper .tooltip:after {
  border-left: solid transparent 10px;
  border-right: solid transparent 10px;
  border-top: solid #1496bb 10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  right: 88%;
  margin-left: -13px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
}

.tooltip_wrapper:hover .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px);
     -moz-transform: translate(0px);
      -ms-transform: translate(0px);
       -o-transform: translate(0px);
          transform: translate(0px);
/* These used to be all translateY */
}

/* Internet Explorer can just show/hide with no transition */
.lte8 .tooltip_wrapper .tooltip {
  display: none;
}
.lte8 .tooltip_wrapper:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1>
Some header to create space
</h1>

<div class='tooltip_wrapper'>?<div class='tooltip'>This is the tooltip text</div></div>
```

I've set up a JSFiddle on that site too, https://jsfiddle.net/rsnbtph7/#&togetherjs=xDN35iPAvV.

Where should I tweak the code so these users aren't disadvantaged?!

Comment: Can confirm on latest chrome I'm seeing it

Comment: The problem is windows trying to display the font. I imagine that font was designed for retina macs, where there are 2x the amount of pixels. Your only option is either increase the font size, or change the font. PS: Firefox is only slightly more readable

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense, this site (http://www.cssfontstack.com) says windows supports Gill Sans only 58%. Does changing the font cure it? I'm pretty frustrated not being able to see!

Comment: See http://i.stack.imgur.com/vteQu.jpg and http://i.stack.imgur.com/azI3R.jpg and http://i.stack.imgur.com/KlsdS.jpg

Comment: OK cool I'll try swapping to Arial, thanks v. much!

Answer (score 0):

[CalvT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1873567/calvt) got it in one - I changed the font to Arial and the problem is now gone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Changing font-family is really works, just paste this line in your css and you will be done.

```
.tooltip {
   font-family: Arial,sans-serif !important;
}
```